# How to know google apis is installed on phone or not?

Tags: android

If i target particular phone to develop application then i need to know full features of that phone. So if i need to know which google apis are installed in that phone, how can i know?

In mobile specification site they don't provide this information.

so is there any other way to know which google apis are provided by the manufacturer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the class you want to use is available like this

```
Class.forName(theclassnameyouneedasasstring);
```

eg for Google maps

```
Class.forName("com.google.android.maps.MapActivity");
```